# php with this array number array(11) [0] => 1

Tags: arrays

Hi need help this result array:
`[0] => 1 [1] => 129 [2] => 122 [3] => 123 [4] => 124 [5] => 125 [6] => 126 [7] => 127 [8] => 128 [9] => 130 [10] => 120`

Need separate elements to:
$value and $key in the mode foreach

```
[0] => 1
```

but as we talk about numbers it's different and everything throws mistakes at me. I'm waiting for your answer Greetings.

ErrorException
Array to string conversion

```
               foreach ($loadDataList  as $key => $value) {
                  echo $key . ' => ' . $value;
                  echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";
              }
```

ErrorException Array to string conversion : `echo $key . ' => ' . $value;`
example from oficial documentation from php

Comment: The [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation has example usage for what you seek.

Comment: yes is posible with name, but with number we are talking about that it is not possible to perform, at least with what is sought to take the data out of the array, I do not see possible to solve it properly.

Comment: `foreach ($loadDataList  as $key => $value) {
                  echo $key . ' => ' . $value;
                   echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";
               }` print error "ErrorException
Array to string conversion"